# CentOS 7 Taskbar/ Panels, Wallpaper & Mouse Disappeared

Tags: centos, virtualbox, desktop-environment

I have Centos 7 running on Virtualbox. There we no major software installations but I after a reboot I find myself with a desktop that does not show a wallpaper, the top and bottom taskbar/panels or the mouse cursor(its invisible but one can right/left click). The desktop seems to be messed up. At the login screen I do see the mouse cursor, post login is when the issue is occurring.

I tried my other Kali and Centos7 VM's and everything shows correctly, so it does not look like its a Virtualbox issue.

Comment: Thank you - makes sense. Is there a way I can move this to the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange?

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851).